# Why I cannot sending Pictures in a React chat app using firebase?

Tags: javascript, react-native, image, expo, firebase-storage

I developed a chat application and i would like to extand with an "image sharing" feature.
I tried many ways to do it and to make it work.
I use Expo Go to test my application on my phone.
Here is the problem: I use expo image picker to select my images in my phone library, but unfortunately i can only rotate or crop my image but I cant send it to the chat, there is no option for that.
What might be the problem? Whit the code or whit the connection with the firebase? Or something else?

```
const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });
  
    if (!result.canceled) {
      setImage(result.uri);
    }
  };


  const storage = getStorage();

  const uploadImage = async (uri) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(uri);
      const blob = await response.blob();
      const storageRef = ref(storage, `images/${new Date().getTime()}`);
      const uploadTask = await uploadString(storageRef, blob, 'data_url');
      return await getDownloadURL(storageRef);
      }catch (error) {
      console.error("Error uploading image: ", error);
    }
  };

  const onSend = useCallback(async (messages = []) => {
    
    if (selectedImage) {
      const {_id, text, createdAt, user} = messages[0];
      // Feltölti a képet a Firebase Storage-ba és megkapja a letöltési URL-t
      const imageUrl = await uploadImage(selectedImage);
      setSelectedImage(null); // Törli a kiválasztott kép állapotát
  
      const messageWithImage = {
        _id: newMessageId, // generálj egy egyedi azonosítót
        createdAt: new Date(),
        user: { _id: userId, avatar: userAvatar }, // felhasználó adatai
        image: imageUrl, // a feltöltött kép URL-je
      };
  
      addDoc(collection(database, 'chats'), messageWithImage);
    }
  
  }, [selectedImage]);
```

Comment: "I cant send it to the chat" Can you explain how that relates to the code you shared? Is there any error message? A specific line that doesn't do what you expect it to do, or maybe even a specific variable that doesn't have the value you expect it to have (when you run in the debugger)?

Comment: I can select in my library on my phone, i can rotate, flip etc and thats all. No error message or anything. Maybe i coudn't connect correctly my code with the firebase?